# Keeping SSH alive in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have a bunch of different services and scripts (MongoDB server, ElasticSearch server and NodeJS) that run on an EC2 instance on Amazon Web Services. These services work fine whenever I'm actively using my own computer to access them and use them from the command line but whenever there is any period of inactivity, longer than a couple of hours I get a broken pipe connection error message.

I've tried setting the ssh config and increasing the ServerAliveInterval value but still whenever I leave the computer unattended or the computer goes to sleep these services cease to work is there any way to force them to stay alive indefinitely?

Comment: I suggest using `screen` instead of trying to keep ssh open. Then everything will still happily run and you don’t need to worry about broken pipes, just reattach when you need to look at things.

Comment: I would question your assumption that all these services use ssh to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

Services like mongod and elasticsearch are usually daemonized (e.g service elasticsearch start) and will continue running in background. But if you are running them as a one of, you can use utilities like nohup and screen to run them in background and kill the nohup process or detach screen as per need.